# Getting an error message in Java while using Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This is one of my very first mini-projects using GUI and Java swing. Everything runs fine with no errors until I invoke the setText() method. Here is my code:

```
public class firstGui implements ActionListener {
    
    private int count = 0;
    private JLabel label;
    private JFrame frame;
    private JButton b;
    
    public firstGui() {
        // Creating the window
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        JPanel panel1 = new JPanel();
        panel1.setBorder(BorderFactory.createEmptyBorder(30, 30, 10, 30));
        panel1.setLayout(new GridLayout(0, 1));
    
        
        // Creating the panel
        frame.add(panel1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setTitle("Here is our first GUI!");
        frame.pack();
        frame.setVisible(true);
        
        // Creating a button to click on
        JButton b = new JButton("Click here! :) ");
        panel1.add(b); 
        // Adding actions to the button when clicked
        
        b.addActionListener(this);
        
        // Creating a label
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Number of times clicked: ");
        panel1.add(label);
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        firstGui user1 = new firstGui();
        
    
        
        

    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        
        count++;
        label.setText("Number of times clicked: " + count); // here is where the problem seems to occur.
        
        
    }

}
```

I'm not sure as to why it gives me a:

```
"Cannot invoke "javax.swing.JLabel.setText(String)" because "this.label" is null" error message.
```

Comment: You're declaring JLabel twice.  The local one is rhe one you are initializing. Same for JFrame and JButton.

Comment: Watch your [class names](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions)

Answer (score 1):

The reason this is happening is because you have used a new *object* for your label.
Rather than using the declared *label* field.

Your following fields here, accessible to any non-static method within the *firstGui* class.

```java
private int count = 0;
private JLabel label;
private JFrame frame;
private JButton b;
```

So, instead of using a new *JLabel* object, here

```java
JLabel label = new JLabel("Number of times clicked: ");
```

Use the same one from the class fields—remove the object type, in the declaration.

```java
label = new JLabel("Number of times clicked: ");
```

Comment: @roTenshi2: 1) Reilas is correct.  Please consider "upvoting" and "acceptinhg" this reply. 2) GENERAL RULES: a) declare and define variables as close to their use as possible, b) Don't declare member variables unless they're being used by different places in your class.  3) Per g00se: Watch your [class names](https://technojeeves.com/index.php/aliasjava1/106-java-style-conventions).  Consider renaming "firstGui" => `FirstGui()`.

Comment: I wouldn't describe it as a "new object." I mean, of course you're creating a new object; you're instantiating a `Label`. The key thing is that it's assigned to a *local variable*.

Comment: @DavidConrad, I don't follow.

Comment: Where you say, "a new *object* for your label," there is only one object regardless of which variable you store it in, whether `this.label` or the local variable `label` which shadows it. So, the problem, I think, is more clearly stated by saying that the local variable `label` is shadowing the field `label`, the field is never assigned, and the local variable goes out of scope at the end of the method. Pedantic, perhaps.

Comment: @DavidConrad, the _label_ field is an object, and the local variable _label_ is an object.  _[Lesson: Classes and Objects (The Java™ Tutorials > Learning the Java Language)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/index.html)_.

Comment: Neither of them are objects. They are variables, which ***refer*** to objects.

Comment: If I write `String a = "Hello"; String b = a;` how many objects do I have? Two? No, one.

Comment: @DavidConrad, I see what you mean, although, I'm referring to the new objects, not the variables.  You're in the wrong context.

Comment: @DavidConrad, there are two objects there.  You might be talking about reference?  _a_ and _b_ are both objects.

Comment: @DavidConrad, for example, _String a, b;_ are two variables, unassigned.  If you assigned both, you have two objects.  You're attempting to say that is the reference is the same, it's the same object.

Comment: No, `a` and `b` both ***refer*** to objects. There is only one object on the heap. And in the Swing case, there is also only one object, the one allocated and initialized by calling `new Label`. To get two objects, you would have to do `new Label` twice.

Comment: If you assign them both to the ***same object*** then there is only ***one*** object, and `a == b`.

Comment: @DavidConrad, exactly, you are referring to the memory allocation, I'm talking about an _object_.  You have your terminology crossed.

Comment: @Reilas "I'm referring to new objects" -- there is only one new object, the one created by `new`.

Comment: I do not have my terminology crossed. I have been programming in Java since 1997 and in general, since 1978. You have your terminology crossed.

Comment: @DavidConrad, you're referring to a reference in memory, not an object.

Comment: The object is the data on the heap. Variables do not contain objects, they only contain the address in memory where the object is found. Of course, normally one doesn't need to think about this when writing code, but it is just wrong to talk about two different objects in this case when only one `JLabel` is ever created by this code.

Comment: @DavidConrad, how about a _method_, is that an object?

Comment: No, of course a method is not an object.

Comment: @DavidConrad, variables, class structures, functions, and procedures, are objects.

Comment: That statement would make Alan Kay very sad. It's also simply incorrect.

Comment: @DavidConrad, good for him.  It's the definition, look it up.  https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_(computer_science).

Comment: @DavidConrad, if I can reiterate.  Computer Science has several contexts, in terms of terminology.  You are referring to memory allocation, which references "objects".  Same word, different context.

Comment: Good for him? He is the one who invented object-oriented programming. If Wikipedia says something different, then Wikipedia is wrong. In a Computer Science context, Alan Kay's definition of 'Object' is the only one that matters. If you don't know who he is, you should not be opining on the subject.

Comment: I should clarify, the point is not about memory allocation. I was only trying, fruitlessly, to get you to see that two variables can refer to the same object. The point is that an object is an instance of a class, and there is only one instance ever created. Even if you assign it to a hundred variables, only one instance exists.

Comment: @DavidConrad, so, hey man, if you want to argue the definition of an object, go to Wikipedia and change it.

Comment: No thanks. If you think an object is not an instance of a class, that's your problem.